# Include TypeScript types in TS export

Tags: typescript

I have a TypeScript library that I want to export for other JS/TS developers to use. As a benefit for users of my library, I'd like to export the types as well. How do I do that? I.e. how do I export a `index.d.ts` type declaration file?

I've looked at the [TypeScript docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/publishing.html#including-declarations-in-your-npm-package), but they seem to talk about writing explicit type declarations, whereas I want to automatically export type declarations when running `npx tsc`.

Here's the `tsconfig.json`:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "lib": ["ES2019"],
    "module": "es6",
    "target": "es5",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "noUnusedParameters": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "build",
    "strict": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
  },
  "include": ["./**/*.ts"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules", ".vscode", "test"]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes writing out a question tells you how to find the answer yourself :)

Adding `--declaration` as specified in the [CLI docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html) does the trick, i.e.:

```
tsc index.js --declaration
```